# how does one normalize a TensorFlow `Dataset` pipeline?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I have my dataset in a TensorFlow `Dataset` pipeline and I am wondering how can I normalize it, The problem is that in order to normalize you need to load your entire dataset which is the exact opposite of what the TensorFlow `Dataset` is for.

So how exactly does one normalize a TensorFlow `Dataset` pipeline? And how do I apply it to new data? (I.E. data used to make a new prediction)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to normalise the entire dataset at once.

Depending on the type of data you work with, you can use a `.map()` function whose sole purpose is to normalise that specific batch of data you are working with (for instance divide by 255.0 each pixel within an image.

You can use, for instance, `map(preprocess_function_1).map(preprocess_function_2).batch(batch_size)`, where `preprocess_function_1()` and `preprocess_function_2()` are two different functions that preprocess a Tensor. If you use `.batch(batch_size)` then the preprocessing functions are applied sequentially on `batch_size` number of elements, you do not need to alter the entire dataset prior to using `tf.data.Dataset()`

Answer (score 2):

There is no other than to iterate through the entire dataset once and collect the information you need. This is what they're doing in the Tensorflow documentation [examples](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/text). For instance here they are getting all the words in order to tokenize the input:

```
tokenizer = tfds.features.text.Tokenizer()

vocabulary_set = set()
for text_tensor, _ in all_labeled_data:
  some_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text_tensor.numpy())
  vocabulary_set.update(some_tokens)

vocab_size = len(vocabulary_set)
```

For normalization you would need to iterate through all the data and keep track of the mean, max, etc.